# EULA Dialog in Android app

Tags: java, android

I want to create an Android app which shows an EULA dialog when the app is opened for the first time only. In that, the app should continue to run normally if the user taps Accept or the app should close if the user taps Decline. If the user has declined it once, he/she should be prompted to Accept the EULA every time he/she opens the app until he/she accepts the EULA.

This is my MainActivity.java in which I want to show the EULA:

```
package com.application;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    boolean agreed = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("agreed",false);

    if(!agreed)
    {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.AlertDialog)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_assignment_late_black_24dp)
                .setTitle(R.string.eula_title)
                .setMessage(R.string.eula)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.accept, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                            {
                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                                editor.putBoolean("agreed", true);
                                editor.apply();
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.decline, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                    {
                        finish();
                    }
                })
                .show();
    }

    private WebView WebView;
    private ProgressBar ProgressBar;
    private LinearLayout LinearLayout;
    private String currentURL;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        ProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        LinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.layout);

        ProgressBar.setMax(100);

        WebView.loadUrl("https://www.domain.tld/index.html");
        WebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        WebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("customUA");
        WebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
        {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)
            {
                LinearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
            {
                LinearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                currentURL = url;
            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView webview, int i, String s, String s1)
            {
                WebView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ErrorActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url2)
            {
                if (url2.contains("www.domain.tld"))
                {
                    view.loadUrl(url2);
                    return false;
                } else
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url2));
                    startActivity(intent);
                    return true;
                }
            }

        });

        WebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()
        {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress)
            {
                super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
                ProgressBar.setProgress(newProgress);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.backward:
                onBackPressed();
                break;

            case R.id.forward:
                onForwardPressed();
                break;

            case R.id.refresh:
                WebView.reload();
                break;

            case R.id.share:
                Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,currentURL);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.shareWith)));
                break;

            case R.id.update:
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UpdateActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                break;

            case R.id.exit:
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this,R.style.AlertDialog)
                        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_error_black_24dp)
                        .setTitle(R.string.title)
                        .setMessage(R.string.message)
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes,
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                                {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                                    {
                                        finish();
                                    }
                                })
                        .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, null)
                        .show();
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void onForwardPressed()
    {
        if (WebView.canGoForward())
        {
            WebView.goForward();
        } else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.noFurther, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed ()
    {
        if (WebView.canGoBack())
        {
            WebView.goBack();
        } else
        {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this,R.style.AlertDialog)
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_error_black_24dp)
                    .setTitle(R.string.title)
                    .setMessage(R.string.message)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                                {
                                    finish();
                                }
                            })
                    .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, null)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, Android studio is marking `if(!agreed)` as an Unexpected token. What should I do to resolve it?

Also, is this approach correct to achieve what I've explained in the beginning?

Comment: I've noticed that you've edited your previous question **very much**.. Now the question has changed, answers given previously are no longer relevant. This is a bad practice on stackoverflow.com.. Don't change/edit your questions by fixing the problem you had, asking if everything is alright now.

Comment: @SerjArdovic I know I shouldn't do that, but, even after one person mentioning the correction and me commenting to him that the problem was solved, others were giving the same input. So, I thought, why not save anyone else's time to correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is caused by wrong Java syntaxis. **You cannot write executable code directly nested inside a class body**, it won't compile!

To make it work, you could enclose your code (`if(!agreed) {...}`) into curly brackets `{if(!agreed){...}}` this will make it an initialiser. *This code will compile correctly, yet in your case you still may have problems..*

**Since you are on Android**, the standard way of running initialization code is to write in inside `onCreate()` callback method, it's the first method to run when a new `Activity` is created.

Answer (score 2):

you cannot add your code there, this is illegal (at least, without declaration of it's scope).

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    if(! sharedPreferences.getBoolean("agreed", false)) {

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.AlertDialog)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_error_black_24dp)
                .setTitle(R.string.eula_title)
                .setMessage(R.string.eula)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.accept, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                    {
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                        editor.putBoolean("agreed", true);
                        editor.apply();

                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.decline, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                    {
                        finish();
                    }
                })
                .show();
    }

...
}
```

Comment: Yeah. I just figured that out and was coming to comment it. What would you say about the question in the end? Would this be enough for the purpose?

Comment: @HrishikeshKokate added a `dialog.dismiss();`

Comment: Somehow, it's working even without that `dialog.dismiss();`. Thanks for the help, though.

Answer (score 2):

Put your (!agreed) block inside onCreate method as in Java this snippet isnt allowed at class its showing the error

```html
if(!agreed)
    {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.AlertDialog)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_error_black_24dp)
                .setTitle(R.string.eula_title)
                .setMessage(R.string.eula)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.accept, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                            {
                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                                editor.putBoolean("agreed", true);
                                editor.apply();
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.decline, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                    {
                        finish();
                    }
                })
                .show();
    }
```